# Impresspages custom plugins Many to Many relation

Tags: impresspages

I have Product table and Tags table, both managed via Grid, How to add multiple tags to products.

Is there a standard way that I can easily achieve or should I make a hack to do it.

There is an example of nested grid, but that's One to Many (photos example).

https://www.impresspages.org/docs/grid

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no standard way to do it. It depends on your needs and relation direction.

You may use Select or Checkboxes field types and custom functions for CRUD actions for that particular field.

If you come up with brilliant idea how many-to-many could work out of the box, it will be definitely added to the core and it won't be a hack anymore =]

Comment: Awesome, I will try to find something that will meet IP quality :)